# At least one true in a column for the same Foreign Key value

Tags: sql, postgresql

There are two tables: `users` and `user_locations`.

`user_locations` structure:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "user_locations" ( 
    "id" UUID NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    "address" VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    "geo_point" POINT NOT NULL,
    "is_current" BOOL NOT NULL,
    "user_id" UUID NOT NULL REFERENCES "users" ("id") ON DELETE CASCADE
);
```

Is there a way to be sure that for the same `user_id` there is at least one true value in the `is_current` column?

**EDIT:** the same `user_id` can have only one true in the `is_current` column

Answer (score 0):

You can get the exceptions using:

```
select u.*
from users u
where not exists (select 1
                  from user_locations ul
                  where ul.user_id = u.id and ul.is_current
                 );
```

You can ensure at least one current value with a trick.  Modify the `users` table to have a `current_user_location` and a generated column that is always true:

```
current_user_location int not null references user_locations(id);

is_current boolean generated always as (true) stored;
```

Add a unique constraint on `user_locations`:

```
alter table user_locations add constraint unq_user_locations_current_id unique (is_current, id);
```

Then, use a foreign key constraint:

```
alter table users add constraint current_user_location 
    foreign key (is_current, current_user_location) references user_locations(is_current, id);
```

Note that this foreign key is referencing the `id` not the `user_id`.  You don't have a requirement that only one user location be current and a unique index/constraint is needed for the foreign key relationship.

Of course, you need to keep `users` up-to-date when you are changing locations.